# Hard time understanding difference between Promise.resolve() and promise chain

Tags: javascript, promise

I have some hard time understanding what is the difference between using Promise.resolve() and simple using the promise.

The explanation seems a bit hard to get so i have a little example:

For example, i have a method that return a promise like this:

```
requestPokemon() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    axios.get("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1").then(value => {
      resolve(value);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      reject(error);
    })
  });
}
```

so, now i can call this method and chain the promise, i figure two ways of do it, and can't get it when Promise.resolve is better or not, my issue is understanding that.

so i solved it in two ways:

**first:**

```
Promise.resolve(this.requestPokemon()).then(value => {
  this.pokemon = value.data.name;
}).catch(error => {
  console.log(error);
})
```

**second:**

```
this.requestPokemon().then(value => {
  this.pokemon = value.data.name;
}).catch(error => {
  console.log(error);
})
```

please i need a little explanation of the downsides and upsides on doing it one way above the other, i appreciate the help a lot.

Thanks

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Comment: You only need the `Promise.resolve` when you don't know whether `this.requestPokemon()` will return a promise, and you want to `.then()` nonetheless

Answer (score 3):

At first you dont need to construct a promise (thats an [antipattern](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it&ved=2ahUKEwjVu_r1ke7aAhWEuhQKHV14B-MQFjAAegQICBAB&usg=AOvVaw1XGu6suV5_8QJtHRJaWdF9)) in your `requestPromise`, just return the one from axios:

```
  requestPokemon() {
    return axios.get("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1");
 }
```

Now lets have a look at this line:

```
 Promise.resolve(this.requestPokemon()).then(/*...*/)
```

It will create a new promise, that resolves or rejects when the axios promise resolves or rejects and adds a then handler to it. So it will be chained like this like this:

```
 resolve() -> Promise (axios) -> Promise (Promise.resolve) -> then
 reject() -> Promise (axios) -> Promise (Promise.resolve) -> catch
```

So as you can see `Promise.resolve` just passes through the data, so actually it is superflous. We actually just need:

```
 resolve() -> Promise (axios) -> then
 reject() -> Promise (axios) -> catch
```

Which can be done with:

```
 this.requestPokemon().then(/*...*/, /*...*/);
```

> please i need a little explanation of the downsides and upsides on doing it one way above the other

Adding `Promise.resolve` is just a bit more typing and makes it less readable, there is no syntactical difference.

Comment: so the call using the Promise constructor is almost never done? just in api calls isn't that the case?

Comment: if i do Promise.resolve i can return the promise and chain it with then and catch, but that is strange to me since i called Promise.resolve() i assume that the promise will be resolved and not fail?

Comment: @af yes, you just need `new Promise` if you want to wrap a callback. And no, if you resolve to a promise (with `resolve(promise)` or `Promise.resolve(promise)`)  it will be flattened, so tue outer promise will do what the inner one does.

Comment: got it, thank you, another thing that confuses me is Promise.resolve and Promise.reject, if i call one of them for example Promise.resolve the parameter that i pass in the resolve, for example a promise should always be resolved? without errors?

Comment: @af if it is not a promise then yes.